# Set width of a single boxplot in c# .net charting

Tags: c#, .net, charts

When I try to show a single BoxPlot in a c# .net Chart, its width always exceeds the xAxis.
The xAxis value type is DateTime.

[image]

is there any way to fix it?
Getting the pixelPosition from value does not work, and returns 0)
I can't retrieve the pixelposition using the index of points, because there is only one point (in the middle of the boxplot)

I add the chart like this:

```
ax.Minimum = minD.AddMinutes(-60).ToOADate();
ax.Maximum = maxD.AddMinutes(+60).ToOADate();

chartDetailsBoxPlot.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();

Series series = new Series
{
    Name = "\nMedian\n25/75 Quantile",
    Color = Color.Red,
    MarkerSize = 100,
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot,
    MarkerBorderWidth = 2,
    MarkerBorderColor = Color.Black,
    BorderColor = Color.Black,
    
};


// min, max, i_min,i_max,median
series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(minD.AddMinutes((maxD - minD).TotalMinutes/2.0).ToOADate(), new double[] { min, max, quantile1, quantile3, median }));

chartDetailsBoxPlot.Series.Add(series);
```

for this example minD = 7h, maxD = 23h. The width should range from 7 o'clock to 23 o'clock

I tried to set PixelPointWidth but the calculation for width is not possible due to the above aspects.